# Site-specific post notice types

Tags: discussion, status-completed, references, moderation

I think it would be useful to have 2 (Skeptics-specific) post notice types:

> **Theoretical Answer**
>
> The central argument of this answer is theoretical in nature. We do not allow answers based uniquely on common sense or pure logic. Answers which are wholly based on a theoretical model are generally downvoted and may be deleted. See [FAQ: What are theoretical answers?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2929)

and

> **Original Research**
>
> This answer is based on original data analysis or non-verifiable data. It is up to the answerer to provide valid, verifiable and potentially replicable evidence. Answers which are wholly based on "original research" are generally downvoted and may be deleted. See [FAQ: What constitutes original research?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924)

What say you? Would it make the site better? Is the wording appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the two new types. Let's hope they lower friction on new users.