# Why was my answer deleted with no reason given?

Tags: discussion, deletion

My [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/41789/5167) to this question was deleted: [Does a mobile plugged in to the charger produce more EM radiation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/does-a-mobile-plugged-in-to-the-charger-produce-more-em-radiation)

No explanation given. The answer does not have a negative score, has references and is accurate. A significant amount of work has been put into it.

If I can improve the answer I will, but no hint as to what merited deletion with it has been given. The "unsourced material" claim is evidently wrong and I asked for it to be removed, again with no response.

Comment: Do the comments on the answer not answer this question for you? They did for me, and I could rehash that here, but I don't honestly see the point.

Comment: No, I explained to those people what their misunderstanding was and then edited the answer to demonstrate the physics aspect (with reference). In fact T.Sar was convinced by my explanation and changed their down vote to an up vote.

Comment: In my opinion, so much of your answer is theoretical in nature - have you read this: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/faq-what-are-theoretical-answers

Comment: I see. Well, I don't think there are any studies proving this but the operation of Doze and the cellular modem is definitely not theoretical, they are vital practical techniques that make modern smart phones possible. But this is all speculation, the moderator chose not to bother explaining their decision.

Comment: For those of us with less than 10K rep (to see deleted answers) you might consider posting a screenshot

Comment: Please don't bring deleted answers to meta. If we deleted them, there's a reason. If seeing them requires 10k, there's a reason. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've left plenty of comments on the question since there were multiple theoretical answers deleted. Here they are:

> I've also had to remove 2 answers which were theoretical in nature. The point of this question is to know whether the EM radiation changes and in which direction (increase, decrease). We all know that there are power saving features. The point is whether this has any noticeable effect based on the plugged in/plugged off variable. In other words, the mechanism by which this claim could be true is secondary. First you need to establish there is an effect, otherwise any explanation is pure fantasy. – Sklivvz♦ yesterday
>
> Moderation note: we've left time and asked the OPs of those questions to fix, but once multiple theoretical answers started to appear and comments started degenerating into a theoretical debate, we decided to delete the posts until they are fixed. We understand deletion is never a good experience and apologise in advance for that, but the site has specific rules for answers which need to be enforced. – Sklivvz♦ yesterday
>
> Since this question seems to attract a lot of theoretical answers (at least 6 so far), further theoretical answers will be deleted more quickly. – Sklivvz♦ yesterday

Comment: This comment isn't on the deleted answer, which I explained to you is not theoretical but based on demonstrable laws of physics and features in the most common mobile OS running on 90% of smart phones. I think you got carried away and shotgunned a good answer along with a bunch of bad ones.

Comment: The answer is based on an API, not on physics. The comment refers to more than one answer which is why is on the question. Sorry for the confusion, you could have looked better before complaining on meta, though. And I am most definitely not going to reiterate why we don't allow theoretical answer as there is plenty of material on meta to address that.

Comment: at least read the answer before condemning it. The big about the physics aspect is right there for you to see if you just take the time. It's not even that long.

Comment: You have 2 links, one to the Android doze API, the other to a transciever. You answer contains many assumptions, many of which completely speculative and not entirely correct, none of which has any evidence to support it. I did read your answer and it's totally deletion worthy according to the rules of this site.