# Is creating a figure based on referenced data original research?

Tags: discussion, answers, original-research

I was thinking about creating and adding a figure to one of [my answers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/40810/36637). I'd use data from [a referenced source](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/tables/expanded-homicide-data-table-4.xls) to create that figure, which would probably take the form of a bar chart or something similar. Is this considered original research? I've found [this answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2925/36637) to the FAQ: "What constitutes original research?". It states:

> Answers are original research when they perform non-trivial analysis of available data and present a novel result which requires specialist expertise to review. It is acceptable to provide a collection of evidence, but not to apply non-trivial calculations that require a community of experts to evaluate. (This also includes the use of non-trivial Internet-based tools.)

So, is creating a bar chart or a similar figure considered a "non-trivial analysis"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, we allow that as long as it's trivial. E.g. a histogram, scatter plot etc are all fine.

The key to not falling into "original research" is that the answer should stand without the plot and it should only serve a further explanation.

For example [this answer of mine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5749/96) is as close as it can get to original research without being so: the plot is a summary and there's independent evidence being presented.