# Oddthinking has 100k reputation!

Tags: discussion

We've just reached a milestone: [User Oddthinking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/23/oddthinking?tab=profile) has reached an incredible **100k reputation**!

[image: 100k for Oddthinking]

I would like to congratulate Oddthinking with this major achievement and his unparalleled contribution to Skeptics.  **Congratulations!** Up to the 200k!

Comment: He should share some with a few bounties.

Comment: Congratulations! Can we start making Jon-Skeet-esque jokes now? "You'll never believe who just reached 100k!...And Oddthinking won't believe it either, without evidence".

Comment: Uh, thank you. That is very nice of you. I don't have a speech prepared, because I am too acutely aware it is only magic Internet points, and doesn't mean much after about 3,000 points gets you all the important privileges.

Comment: @fredsbend: I have considered throwing bounty points at Glorfindel, who has been tirelessly working on a long campaign to fix old broken links. At only 2 rep points an edit, he has a long way to go to get to the point where his edits don't need to be pre-approved. I am just worried it will look untoward for a mod to shower points on an individual as a workaround for the privilege system.

Comment: Tagging @Glorfindel so I am not talking behind his back.

Comment: @RToyo: Oh, please no. No-one wants the deification of mods here. We are humans, we make mistakes, we should be (politely?) challenged when we do.

Comment: @Oddthinking you still don't know about the Skeptics rep store? Why do you think I have so little? ;) Anyway, congrats!

Comment: @Oddthinking (about Glorfindel): And not just on this site - I see his edits popping up everywhere ;-)

Comment: I would like to add that @Oddthinking has probably one of the best avatars possible for a moderator for Skeptics.SE. Congrats on the 100k!

Comment: @RToyo Oddthinking wrote and posted a lengthy acceptance speech, describing first-hand his journey to 100k and how the responsibility of being a moderator has changed his life. Then he deleted it because it was based on [original research](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/faq-what-constitutes-original-research).

Comment: @RToyo Legend has it that Oddthinking can *[non-notable claim removed]*

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: @Oddthinking But [@replies doesn't work unless the person has previously commented or is the post owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/390963), so Glorfindel hasn't actually been notified. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Graham: What you're missing is that I may have 100K rep but I still haven't worked out the corner cases of this software :-(